# How can I extract XML text using python BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract dialog from the [Folger Library Shakespeare TEI XML editions](http://www.folgerdigitaltexts.org/). A typical chunk of dialog looks like this:

```
<sp xml:id="sp-0024" who="#HORATIO">
<speaker xml:id="spk-0024">
<w xml:id="w0003030">HORATIO</w>
</speaker>
<ab xml:id="ab-0024">
<join type="line" xml:id="ftln-0024" n="1.1.24" ana="#short" target="#w0003040 #c0003050 #w0003060 #c0003070 #w0003080 #c0003090 #w0003100 #p0003110"/>
<w xml:id="w0003040" n="1.1.24">A</w>
<c xml:id="c0003050" n="1.1.24"> </c>
<w xml:id="w0003060" n="1.1.24">piece</w>
<c xml:id="c0003070" n="1.1.24"> </c>
<w xml:id="w0003080" n="1.1.24">of</w>
<c xml:id="c0003090" n="1.1.24"> </c>
<w xml:id="w0003100" n="1.1.24">him</w>
<pc xml:id="p0003110" n="1.1.24">.</pc>
</ab>
</sp>
```

I basically want to get output that looks like this: 
    ['Horatio','A piece of him.'] 
but for all the dialog of a particular character. In other words, I want to be able to input the Folger Shakespeare TEI XML file and output files like gertrude.txt and horatio.txt each containing all the collected dialog from that particular character.

I can get all the dialog/stage direction/etc of a particular speaker with `soup.find_all(who=u'#GERTRUDE')` but then I can't seem to do anything else with the results, like drill down further, get the text between the tags, etc, without re-parsing the data all over again. Here's what happens:

```
>>> gertrude=soup.find_all(who=u'#GERTRUDE')
>>> gertrude.w
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'w'
>>> gertrude.get_text()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: Why not use `lxml` directly?

Comment: Two points: how are you trying to use the data? Can you post a larger sample that would be a useful sample size for your testing against your use case. Yes, we can help you extract the data, but there's an amount of interpretation to do, so knowing how you want to use it is important.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'll look into that, thanks. I don't know anything about parsing XML so I just chose the first thing I heard of.

Comment: @MattH, Fair enough. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Jono: Shucks, I was hoping for a larger sample to get a clear picture of the document and how it relates to character dialogue. You're still not making much sense about how you want to use the data. You're saying you want all the lines of dialogue for each character in a named character file. And then you say you know how to get the stage direction. Personally, I'd imagine the relative position of the dialogue and directions is important but you seem to indicate that it isn't.

Comment: @MattH, It's just the Folger Shakespeare TEI texts. Link above. I've pasted a sample of one here: http://pastebin.com/wuMHxjXX I'm just trying to get the dialog for each character into separate text files.

Comment: Usually I don't have to register with websites in order to answer questions on SO

Comment: @MattH, Fair enough. I forgot they make you register. Anyway it shouldn't matter, since the relevant code is above and a longer snippet is in the pastebin link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup's `.find_all()` method returns a `ResultSet` object, which is a specialized kind of list. You have 0 or more matches, and you need to either loop over that result set or use indexing to get at individual elements contained in the result set:

```
for speaker in soup.find_all(who=u'#GERTRUDE'):
```